# Collection parameter in method/constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

When some method/constructor accepts a collection parameter, should the parameter type be used as `IEnumerable` most of the time ? If so, should the method create a new List (`.ToList()`) to store the reference in a private variable or in method scoped local variable instead of storing the variable in a `IEnumerable` type variable?

Please let me know.

Comment: Your question is too vague. It depends on a lot of context. Sometimes you'll want to copy the collection - sometimes you won't. Sometimes `IEnumerable<T>` is enough - sometimes it's not.

Comment: And sometimes you want to keep a reference to the parameter itself, sometimes you may prefer to copy it to a ReadOnlyCollection or cast it to an IReadOnlyList ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should the parameter type be used as IEnumerable most of the time ?

*If* you really mean `IEnumerable<T>` then yes. Unless the type needs something richer, then you could use one of the interfaces that extend `IEnumerable<T>`.

You should avoid the non-generic interfaces and collections (namespace `System.Collections`) in favour of generic ones (namespace `System.Collections.Generic`).

> If so, should the method create a new List (.ToList()) to store the reference in a private variable or in method scoped local variable instead of storing the variable in a IEnumerable type variable?

Possibly yes.

The answer depends on the semantics of your type. If defined as holding a reference to the collection then don't copy it (eg. multiple `ContactPerson` in an `Organisation` may all share the list of `Interaction` with that organisation). In other cases where the new object will own the collection then it should make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should use it in a way, that makes you sure you're iterating over the collection only once.

So if you're just using simple `foreach` `IEnumerable` is OK, but if you'd like to make more complex things you should store it locally (using `ToList()`, `ToArray()` or similar) and than use that local variable instead of iterating over source collection over and over.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use only for Read - use `IEnumerable`, if you want to update the collection, by `Add`, `Remove` elements, you should cast to a collection type which allows you to do these actions